# What can and can't I specialize in the std namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, explicit-specialization

Users are allowed to add explicit specializations to the `std` namespace. However, there are a few templates that I am explicitly forbidden from specializing.

What templates can and can't I specialize?

Comment: What, exactly, are you looking for in an answer?  Really, if you want to specialize something, you must consult the specification.  Most Standard Library components impose requirements on specializations.  A complete answer of what you can and cannot specialize and what the restrictions are on specializations would be far too long for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: By "specialize functions", I assume you mean "specialize function templates"? By the way, does C++11 allow partial function template specialization?

Comment: partial specialization of function templates is not allowed, use function overloading instead. see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Quoting loosely from the standard:

- `numeric_limits` shall not be specialized for non-arithmetic standard types (e.g. `complex<T>`)
- "[S]pecializations of `shared_ptr` shall be CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable, and LessThanComparable [and] convertible to `bool`."
- "Specializations of `weak_ptr` shall be CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable."
- "[T]emplate specializations [of `std::hash`] shall meet the requirements of class template hash."
- Anything in `<type_traits>`: "The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the class templates defined in this subclause is undefined unless otherwise specified." (only some specializations of `common_type` are explicitly allowed)
- Locales have certain *required* specializations.
- All specializations of `istreambuf_iterator` shall have a trivial copy constructor, a constexpr default constructor, and a trivial destructor.
- "The effect of instantiating the class template `complex` for any type other than float, double, or long double is unspecified." I take it that means that defining such other  specializations is pointless.
- "Specializations and instantiations of the `atomic` template shall have a deleted copy constructor, a deleted copy assignment operator, and a constexpr value constructor."
- "The class templates `unary_function` and `binary_function` are deprecated. A program shall not declare specializations of these templates."

And of course the overarching clause 17.6.4.2.1, sentence 1 (thanks @sehe and @curiousguy):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
> namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization
> for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
> and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
> prohibited.

And sentence 2:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares
>
> - an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template, or
> - an explicit specialization of any member function template of a standard library class or class template, or
> - an explicit or partial specialization of any member class template of a standard library class or class template.
>
> A program may explicitly instantiate a template defined in the standard library only if the declaration
> depends on the name of a user-defined type and the instantiation meets the standard library requirements
> for the original template.

Comment: I expect specialisations of `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` to be much more than CopySomething!

Comment: "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only (...) the specialization **meets the standard library requirements for the original template**"

Comment: How about specialising `default_delete` in the `std` namespace?