# Why is digits10 for reference to integer type 0?

Tags: c++

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::digits10 << "\n" 
              << std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t&>::digits10 << "\n";
}
```

outputs

> 19
>   0

I would expect `std::uint64_t&` to have same value as `std::uint64_t`: Is there a reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits` doesn't specialize on that type, so it is 0 by default.

Comment: from a language design perspective, shouldn't the default be a compiling error?

Comment: No specific reason - it's just making reference types to have the same values in `numeric_limits` as the non-reference requires additional effort, and nobody thought to make it convenient for you. You can `std::remove_reference<T>::type` if that concerns you.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Arguably.

Answer (score 2):

18.3.2.1/2:

> Specializations shall be provided for each arithmetic type, both
>   floating point and integer, including bool. The member is_specialized
>   shall be true for all such specializations of numeric_limits.

So we know that specializations will exist for for these non-reference types. Then 18.3.2.3/1:

> The default numeric_limits template shall have all members, but
>   with 0 or false values.

I suspect it was done this way because you can always static_assert on `is_specialized` to force a compile error, but there could possibly be some template application where 0 would be an ok default value for one or more of the limits. If you want to be able to test references just run it through `std::remove_reference`.

I'm not sure if it's legal to specialize `numeric_limits` for your own types. The standard in 18.3.2.1/4 says:

> Non-arithmetic standard types, such as complex (26.4.2), shall not
>   have specializations.

I personally read this qute as "the standard will not provide specializations for non-arithmetic standard libray types, but it's perfectly legal to specialize for a user type". You could just as easily read this as totally forbidding any non-provided specializations.

Comment: seems like a lame mistake, but for now this is the best A, if somebody does not come up with an answer explaining the reasoning I will accept. :)

Comment: Specializing `std::numeric_limits` for non-arithmetic `T`s [is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace).

Comment: @MarkB I was referring to: "numeric_limits shall not be specialized for non-arithmetic standard types". You can't specialize it in the `std` namespace, to my understanding (others should be allowed btw). Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

The type `uint64&` is a reference, so it's not one of the arithmetic types that the `numeric_limits` template should be used for.

For any other types than the arithmetic types defined, the default definition is used which contains:

```
static const int  digits10 = 0;
```

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/

Answer (score 0):

`std::numeric_limits` is expected to be specialized for fundamental arithmetic data types (integers and floating points). A reference -of any kind- does not belong to them and that's why the non-specialized template is chosen, which has all its members to `false` (`0`).

> I would expect std::uint64_t& to have same value as std::uint64_t: Is
>   there a reason for this discrepancy?

Although `std::uint64_t` is an arithmetic type, `std::uint64_t&` is a compound type and has a different meaning. You have a few options:

- Always consider the base type by removing the reference, pointer or both.
- `static_assert( is_arithmetic<> )`
- check `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized`