# How to specialize std::begin?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, template-function

I'm trying to specialize `std::begin` for a custom container. I'm doing this because I want to use range-based `for` with the container. This is what I have:

```
class stackiterator { … };
class stack { … };

#include <iterator>

template <> stackiterator std::begin(stack& S)
{
  return S.GetBottom();
}
```

I get the following error at the definition of my `begin` specialization:

> No function template matches function template specialization 'begin'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create a begin member function for your stack class that returns an iterator and you wont need template specialization.

Comment: Why don't you implement `stack::begin()` and just use the implementation of `std::begin()` as is?

Comment: @RSahu Because the naming conventions of the project use PascalCase for functions.

Comment: Or write a free `begin` that is found by ADL. You shouldn't really be writing `std::begin(stuff)` anyway.

Comment: @AkashPradhan I'd prefer to specialize `std::begin` because [see my previous comment].

Comment: @T.C. That too would be against the project's naming conventions. Why not `std::begin(stuff)`?

Comment: Because it's not how customization points are supposed to be used, and will not work with range-based `for`, for instance; and because it's impossible; specializing a function template can't change the return type, and the one you want to specialize returns "whatever member `begin()` returns", which obviously won't work if you don't have a member `begin()`.

Comment: @zenith, So that you can find other `begin` functions through ADL. It's messy and Eric Niebler proposed a solution to make `std::begin` (and other customization points) do all that so that we don't end up having a repetitive bunch of using statements at the top of functions that grows larger as the list of customization points grows.

Comment: I would think that the standard takes priority over coding conventions... You should double-check about writing a member begin function.

Comment: @T.C. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8165154/3425536), you can specialize `std::begin()` to make it work with range-based `for`. Oh and I didn't know that specializations can't change return types, thanks.

Comment: That's a defect changed by [CWG 1442](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1442).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I'm trying to specialize `std::begin` for a custom container. I'm
>   doing this because I want to use range-based `for` with the container.

You are barking up the wrong tree. Range-based `for` does not use `std::begin` at all. For class types, the compiler looks up member `begin` and `end` directly, and if neither is found, does an ADL-only lookup for free `begin` and `end` in the associated namespaces. Ordinary unqualified lookup is not performed; there's no way for `std::begin` to be picked up if your class is not in the `std` namespace.

Even if the specialization you want to do is possible (it isn't unless you introduce a member `begin()` - an explicit specialization for a function template can't change the return type, and the overload at issue returns "whatever member `begin()` returns"; and if you do introduce a member `begin()`, why are you specializing `std::begin` to do what it would have done anyway?), you still won't be able to use it with a range-based `for`.

Comment: Then what does [this (accepted) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8165154/3425536) mean when it says that range-based `for` compatibility can be achieved by specializing `std::begin`? Is it just wrong?

Comment: @zenith It's outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the policy and semantic issues of whether you should specialize a function template from the `std` namespace,

The following snippet does not work:

```
class stackiterator {};
struct stack { stackiterator Begin() { return stackiterator{};} };

#include <iterator>

namespace std
{
   template <> stackiterator begin<stack>(stack& S)
   {
      return S.Begin();
   }
}
```

However, the following snippet works just fine:

```
class stackiterator {};
struct stack { stackiterator begin() { return stackiterator{};} };

#include <iterator>

namespace std
{
   template <> stackiterator begin<stack>(stack& S)
   {
      return S.begin();
   }
}
```

The key difference is the presence of `Begin()` vs `begin()` as a member function of `stack`. `std::begin()` is defined as:

```
template <class C> auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
template <class C> auto begin(const C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

When you specialize a function template, you must still keep the return type the same. When you don't have `begin()` as a member of `Stack`, the compiler does not know how to determine the return type.

That is the reason for error produced by the compiler.

BTW, there is [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace) that partially answers what can be specialized and what can't be specialized.

Looking at the part of the standard that deals with `std::begin()`, Section 24.3, I don't see anything about not being able to specialize `std::begin()`.

Comment: If you already have a member `begin()`, why on earth would you want to specialize `std::begin()`?

Comment: @TC, was that comment for me or the OP?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to add a free function `begin` that enables `for(:)` loops is to add, in the namespace of `stack`, a `begin(stack&)` and `begin(stack const&)` function that returns a iterator and const_iterator respectively (and ditto for `end`)

The other way is to add a member `begin()` and `end()` to `stack`.

Specializing `std::begin` is bad practice for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that not all `for(:)` loops will work with it (the lookup rules where changed [in the resolution of this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1442)).  Overloading `std::begin` is undefined behavior (you may not overload functions in `namespace std` under the standard: doing so makes your program ill-formed).

This is how it has to be done, even if it violates the naming convention of your project.

Comment: Note that it was supposed to be a specialization of `std::begin` (not an overload) since those are allowed by the standard.