# Is it legal to specialize std library functions for a shared_ptr of a user defined type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The standard says the following about specializing templates from the standard library (via [What can and can't I specialize in the std namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace) )

> A program may add a template
>   specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only
>   if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the
>   specialization meets the standard library requirements for the
>   original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

Is it legal to specialize standard library templates with a standard library class specialized with a user defined class?

For example, specializing `std::hash` for `std::shared_ptr<MyType>`?

From reading the above paragraph and linked question, it sounds like it should be, as the declaration of the specialization is dependent on `MyType`, however "Unless explicitly prohibited" worries me slightly.

The example below compiles and works as expected (AppleClang 7.3), but is it legal?

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

struct MyType {
    MyType(std::string id) : id(id) {}
    std::string id;
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<shared_ptr<MyType>> {
        size_t operator()(shared_ptr<MyType> const& mine) const {
            return hash<string>()(mine->id);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct equal_to<shared_ptr<MyType>> {
        bool operator()(shared_ptr<MyType> const& lhs, shared_ptr<MyType> const& rhs ) const {
            return lhs->id == rhs->id;
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<MyType>> mySet;
    auto resultA = mySet.emplace(std::make_shared<MyType>("A"));
    auto resultB = mySet.emplace(std::make_shared<MyType>("B"));
    auto resultA2 = mySet.emplace(std::make_shared<MyType>("A"));
    assert(resultA.second);
    assert(resultB.second);
    assert(!resultA2.second);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is legal, there are no restrictions on specialization of `std::hash` except *DefaultConstructible, CopyAssignable, Swappable and Destructible* (and all other requirements that has nothing to do with *"explicitly prohibited"*). One example of *"explicitly prohibited"* specialization is specializing `std::numeric_limits` for non-arithmetic standard types.

Comment: You should have a look at Argument Dependend lookup, you don't need to add functions to the std namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is legal.

It is even questionably legal to specialize for `std::shared_ptr<int>` at one point; I don't know if they patched that ambiguity in the standard as a defect or not.

Note that that is a poor implemenation of a hash for global use.  First, because it doesn't support null shared pointers.  Second, because hashing a shared pointer as always the int value is questionable.  It is even dangerous, because if a shared pointer to an int in a container has that int change, you just broke the program.

Consider making your own hasher for these kind of cases.

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class T, class=void>
  struct hasher_impl:std::hash<T>{};

  namespace adl_helper {
    template<class T>
    std::size_t hash( T const& t, ... ) {
      return ::notstd::hasher_impl<T>{}(t);
    }
  };
  namespace adl_helper2 {
    template<class T>
    std::size_t hash_helper(T const& t) {
      using ::notstd::adl_helper::hash;
      return hash(t);
    }
  }
  template<class T>
  std::size_t hash(T const& t) {
    return ::notstd::adl_helper2::hash_helper(t);
  }

  struct hasher {
    template<class T>
    std::size_t operator()(T const& t)const {
      return hash(t);
    }
  };

}
```

Now this permits 3 points of customization.

First, if you override `std::size_t hash(T const&)` in the namespace containing `T`, it picks it up.

Failing that, if you specialize `notstd::hasher_impl<T, void>` for your type `T`, it picks it up.

Third, if both of those fail, it invokes `std::hash<T>`, picking up any specializations.

Then you can do:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<MyType>, ::notstd::hasher> mySet;
```

and add:

```
struct MyType {
  MyType(std::string id) : id(id) {}
  std::string id;
  friend std::size_t hash( MyType const& self) {
    return ::notstd::hash(self.id);
  }
  friend std::size_t hash( std::shared_ptr<MyType> const& self) {
    if (!self) return 0;
    return ::notstd::hash(*self);
  }
};
```

which should give you a smart hash on on `shared_ptr<MyType>`.

This keeps the danger that someone changes `id` on a `shared_ptr<MyType>` which breaks every container containing the `shared_ptr<MyType>` in a non-local manner.

Shared state is the devil; consider writing a copy on write pointer if you are really worried about copying these things being expensive.