# Shouldn't `std::shared_ptr` use `std::default_delete` by default?

Tags: c++, default, shared-ptr, delete-operator, c++20

[`std::default_delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) [can be specialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace) to allow [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)s to [painlessly manage types which have to be destroyed by calling some custom destroy-function instead of using `delete p;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957671).

There are basically two ways to make sure an object is managed by a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in C++:

1. Create it managed by a shared-pointer, using [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) or [`std::allocate_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared). This is the preferred way, as it coalesces both memory-blocks needed (payload and reference-counts) into one. Though iff there are only [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)s left, the need for the reference-counts will by necessity still pin down the memory for the payload too.
2. Assign management to a shared-pointer afterwards, using [a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) or [`.reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset).

The second case, when not providing a custom deleter is interesting:

Specifically, it is defined to use its own deleter of unspecified type which uses `delete [] p;` or `delete p;` respectively, depending on the `std::shared_ptr` being instantiated for an Array or not.

Quote from n4659 (~C++17):

> ```
> template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* p);
> ```
>
> 4 Requires: `Y` shall be a complete type. The expression `delete[] p`, when `T` is an array type, or `delete p`, when `T` is not an array type, shall have well-deﬁned behavior, and shall not throw exceptions.
>   5 Eﬀects: When `T` is not an Array type, constructs a `shared_ptr` object that owns the pointer `p`. Otherwise, constructs a `shared_ptr` that owns `p` and a deleter of an unspeciﬁed type that calls `delete[] p`. When `T` is not an array type, enables `shared_from_this` with `p`. If an exception is thrown, `delete p` is called when `T` is not an array type, `delete[] p` otherwise.
>   6 Postconditions: `use_count() == 1 && get() == p`.
>   […]
>
> ```
> template<class Y> void reset(Y* p);
> ```
>
> 3 Eﬀects: Equivalent to `shared_ptr(p).swap(*this)`.

My questions are:

1. Is there a, preferably good, reason that it is not specified to use `std::default_delete` instead?
2. Would any valid (and potentially useful?) code be broken by that change?
3. Is there already a proposal to do so?

Comment: Well, your specialization has to "meet the standard library requirements for the original template", and part of said requirements is that it calls `delete` (or `delete[]`). I don't see how you can legally specialize it to do something else.

Comment: Does the default delete still work when the control block is created with the same memory block as the instance. (Weak pointers require a different moment of destruction)

Comment: @T.C. The specialization deletes the object, in the only proper way. The base template would have been wrong, so no problem.

Comment: @JVApen: There is no separate deleter used if `std::make_shared` or `std::allocate_shared` coalesce both allocations. That's only background for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a, preferably good, reason that it is not specified to use `std::default_delete` instead?

Because it wouldn't do what you want. See, just because you can specialize something doesn't mean you can hijack it. The standard says ([namespace.std]):

> A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

The standard library requirement for `std::default_delete<T>::operator()(T* ptr)`'s behavior is that it "Calls `delete` on `ptr`." So your specialization of it *must* do the same.

As such, there should be no difference between having `shared_ptr` perform `delete ptr;` and having `shared_ptr` invoke `default_delete<T>{}(ptr)`.

This is why `unique_ptr` takes a deleter type, rather than relying on you to specialize it.

---

From the comments:

> The specialization deletes the object, in the only proper way.

But that's not what the requirement says. It says "Calls `delete` on `ptr`." It does not say something more ambiguous like "ends the lifetime of the object pointed to by `ptr`" or "destroys the object referenced by `ptr`". It gives explicit code that must happen.

And your specialization has to follow through.

If you remain unconvinced, the paper [P0722R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0722r1.html) says this:

> Note that the standard requires specializations of `default_delete<T>` to have the same effect as calling `delete p;`,

So clearly, the authors agree that specializing `default_delete` is not a mechanism for adding your own behavior.

So the premise of your question is invalid.

---

However, let's pretend for a moment that your question were valid, that such a specialization would work. Valid or not, specializing `default_delete` to customize deleter behavior is not the *intended* method of doing so. If it were the intent, you wouldn't need a deleter object for `unique_ptr` at all. At most, you would just need a parameter that tells you what the pointer type is, which would default to `T*`.

So that's a good reason not to do this.

Comment: Regarding the last point of your answer, pretending that specializing `default_delete` to call a custom `destroy` instead of `delete` is valid, there would still be a benefit to having a deleter for `unique_ptr` when you want to use different deleters for the same `T`. That might not be a very good use-case (strong types over `T` might be a good idea), but it does exist.

Comment: So, to summarize: No to all three questions, but any useful specialialization of `std::default_delete` is invalid so it doesn't really matter?