# Can you specialize std::unique_lock

Tags: c++, locking, c++14, mutex, c++17

A mutex we use has a strange interface (weird casing for example). Having a specialization for `std::unique_lock` would help reduce the cognitive overhead of using this mutex.

I couldn't find anything in the standard that specifically allowed specializing `std::unique_lock`. Thinking about it, I don't see any downsides off the top of my head to allowing specializations of `std::unique_lock`. Can someone confirm that it is indeed unspecified by the standard (and thus undefined behavior following the quote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513497)?

If it is permitted, could someone point me to the section in the standard that says that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specialize `std::unique_lock` for your own mutex type:

[[namespace.std]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/library#namespace.std-1)

> A program may add a template specialization for any standard library
>   template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a
>   user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library
>   requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited.

There is nothing in the section for `std::unique_lock` to explicitly prohibit specialization. Thus the general rule applies.