# Is it ok to specialize std::pointer_traits?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-traits, fancy-pointers

Standard documentation says this about a specialization of `std::pointer_traits`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits

"A specialization for user-defined fancy pointer types may provide an additional static member function to_address to customize the behavior of std::to_address. "

**This seems to imply that one can specialize this `std` class.
Is this correct?**

I need to do this for a fancy pointer class I don't control, but doesn't work with `std::pointer_traits::rebind` (which doesn't do the correct substitutions for this particular pointer class).

A similar question has been asked here [What can and can't I specialize in the std namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace) but the specific case of `pointer_traits` was not addressed.

---

**NOTE**: I need this because pointer rebinding otherwise doesn't work out of the box for a pointer type I do not control.

```
template<class... As>
struct std::pointer_traits<::thrust::pointer<As...>>
: ::thrust::detail::pointer_traits<thrust::pointer<As...>> {
    template<class T>
    using rebind = typename ::thrust::detail::pointer_traits<::thrust::pointer<As...>>::template rebind<T>::other;
};
```

Comment: It is generally legal to provide specializations for the templates defined in the standard library, as long as a) at least one parameter is a user-defined type, and b) the specialization satisfies all the requirements placed on the original template.

Comment: [What can and can't I specialize in the std namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace)

Comment: @user12002570, thanks! what of the rules in the linked answer applies best to this case? std::pointer_traits is not in <type_traits> (is in <memory>).