# std::unique_ptr custom deleter

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Reference [Well, how does the custom deleter of std::unique_ptr work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274451/well-how-does-the-custom-deleter-of-stdunique-ptr-work)

Constructor

```
std::unique_ptr<ErrorHandling> error_;

RecursiveDescentParser::RecursiveDescentParser(std::string inputStream, bool fileService, 
            boost::optional<std::string> filePathName, std::ofstream &writer){

    if (fileService == true){
        error_(new ErrorHandling(fileService, writer));  <---- compiler error
    }
    else{
        error_(new ErrorHandling(fileService, std::ofstream())); <---- compiler error
    }       
}
```

Compiler error

```
Error   1   error C2247: 'std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()' not accessible because 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' uses 'private' to inherit from 'std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx,_Empty_deleter>'
```

Cause of error described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1ktd2d9(v=vs.80).aspx).

I decided since `'std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()` is `private` because child class (`std::unique_ptr` in this case) has specified `private inheritance` that I would write my own custom deleter.  Problem is I am too uncomfortable with the syntax and notation to succeed.

Comment: Is the destructor of `ErrorHandling` declared `private`?

Comment: I had actually not declared a destructor (synthesized) and formally declared one but the compiler error remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
error_(new ErrorHandling(fileService, writer));
```

is an error because `unique_ptr` doesn't have an `operator()`. The error message is a bit misleading, because its base class seems to have one (but luckily private).

You probably intended

```
error_.reset(new ErrorHandling(fileService, writer));
```

which makes the `unique_ptr` own a new object.

Comment: Even if there is no initial object, it is safe to call reset to initialize a std::unique_ptr?

Comment: Yes, the default constructor you used will set the initial pointer to null. It's quite ok to replace that with a real pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're trying to use the function-call operator on a `unique_ptr`, which is not a valid thing to do. Then some confusion is caused because your particular implementation happens to have an inaccessible operator, rather than no operator at all, giving a weird error message.

I assume you're actually trying to reset `error_` to own a new pointer:

```
error_.reset(new ErrorHandling(fileService, writer));
//    ^^^^^^
```

UPDATE: if you do want a custom deleter (which, to reiterate, you don't in this situation), it might look like:

```
struct ErrorHandlingDeleter
{
    void operator()(ErrorHandling * p) {/* do something to release the pointer */}
};

std::unique_ptr<ErrorHandling, ErrorHandlingDeleter> error;
```

Comment: I was trying the following syntax `std::unique_ptr<ErrorHandling> error_(new ErrorHandling(fileService, writer));` but received the compilation error proceeding what I thought was a need to define my own custom deleter. Even though utilizing `reset` is the solution, can I please see a SSCCE custom deleter example?

Comment: @Mushy: That's the syntax to declare and initialise a new unique pointer. However, you don't want to do that; you want to modify an existing one, and for that you need to call `reset`. `error_(some_pointer)` does something completely different - it tries to call the unique pointer like a function, which is impossible.

Comment: @Mushy: For an example of custom deleters, Google pointed me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274451 and many other places. But of course, you don't want a custom deleter here; they are only for when `delete` isn't the right thing to do.

Comment: That link I have referenced at the top of my question.  The syntax of that link was not very clear to me and thus I decided to ask for a clearer example. Not even my textbook provides a very clear example.

Comment: @Mushy: OK, I've added an example of a custom deleter. I've no idea whether that's clearer than your textbook, though.