# Is there a class/template in std library to perform a task when out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11

We have some resource, which need to be manually released. Except explicitly writing a RAII wrapper for managing its resource, is any built-in template or class in std library to automatically perform a lambda task?

```
{
    auto resource = InitResource();        
    GuardedTask task ([&resource]{ FreeUp(resource); }); // Simply bind a clean up lambda
    ...
    if(failed_condition_met) { return false; } // Free up
    ...
    if(another_failed_condition_met) { return false; } // Free up

} // Free up
```

The class may behavior like the following, but I am wondering that wheel may be already built in std library, or I should write my own one.

```
struct GuardedTask
{
    std::function<void()> task;
    GuardedTask(std::function<void()> f): task(f) {}
    ~GuardedTask(){ task(); }
};
```

Comment: Note that you have to delete copy constructor/assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern is called a scope guard and has many other uses than RAII cleanup such as transaction safe functions. Unfortunately, there is no standardized scope guard but there is proposal [P0052](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0052r2.pdf) that intended to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom deleter on `std::unique_ptr`.

Cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274451/well-how-does-the-custom-deleter-of-stdunique-ptr-work#8274548).

Comment: The unique_ptr with custom deleter is good. But it is useful for kind of single resource, and I need care the T and Deleter Type in unique_ptr. Sometimes I want a "Clean Task" just in charge for this one-time scope, by simply passing a lambda.

Comment: Hm, I don't think there is a conceptually clean way to do that. I don't know if you have ever written C, but the crux is, even if you write a single exit point for a function, the different exit states of the function need to be handled differently. Thus, in C++, you should usually ensure that a resource is handled automatically after it's creation. If you have a single function to free up many things, some of them may not be initialized (e.g. if a constructor throws), which may lead to surprising failures in your exit block, or to complicated logic.