Safe passing of pointer from a shared library
I need to implement a solution where shared library provides a class SomeClass, and its factory SomeClassFactory returning a pointer to SomeClass. The reason, why it's a pointer, not a static object is that it is actually an interface. I am aware that if a raw pointer is returned, this causes problems regarding the object lifetime management, and usually it should be SomeClassFactory responsibility to delete that object, which it created.
I came across a solution when std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> is returned from the shared library, or its variation, when exported public method in fact returns a raw pointer, but it is immediately wrapped around std::unique_ptr on the client side, like this:
class SomeClassFactory
{
    public:
        inline static std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> create() 
        { 
            return std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>(doCreate()); 
        }

    private:
        SomeClassFactory();
        static SomeClass *doCreate()
        {
            return new SomeClass();
        }
};

To me, this seems to work already, but I also found the following addition to this code, which apparently must be added:
template<>
class std::default_delete<SomeClass>
{
public:
  void operator()(SomeClass *classPtr)
  {
     delete classPtr;
  }
};

I understand that it is the specialization of the custom deleter for SomeClass, used in the context of unique_ptr, but the question is: is it really necessary? My understanding would be that custom deleter is created for SomeClass only if some special operation is performed. Here, the deletion is pretty standard, so what is the purpose of this specialization?

"apparently must be added" why you came to this conclusion?

You should ask the person who added the specialisation. Without further information, it's not necessary, compiler will generate almost exactly the same thing for you.

its also unclear why you need doCreate. Instead you can simply return std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>(); or return {}; should do aswell

This is not [mcve]. I suspect that your interface doesn't define a virtual destructor and that is why you are doing some strange hacking to overcome this mistake.

If you do this, then at least return a shared pointer to an abstract baseclass (really helpful for unit testing/dependency injection). This also helps with your deleter function because you will be deleting a base class with a virtual destructor

why you came to this conclusion? - I found two different occasions, where this idiom was used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274451/how-does-the-custom-deleter-of-stdunique-ptr-work and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594671/How-to-Ensure-Proper-Dynamic-Library-Boundary-Cros

@MarekR - I am not doing "strange hacking", I am following answers that I found in the web, that independently suggest it, see the links in my comment above. My question is: what is the purpose of this specialization, if deletion of the underlying object would be safe without it?

Be aware that web is full of beginners which are trying their best, but they are misleading other beginners.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai - the reason for doCreate is probably to move using the unique_ptr from the library to the client side.

@MarekR - yes, but it's not common to have two different beginners coming with the same faulty or misleading recommendation. Also, these answers are in well rated articles on codeproject and SO, respectively, so I suppose there must be sth. in it.

Anyway please provide [mcve]! Here is my live example of using polymorphism across dynamic library: https://godbolt.org/z/dW176478b

If you are compiling your entire C++ codebase with one compiler then you don't need to do anything fancy, you just allocate the object with std::make_unique<SomeClass>() anywhere and your compiler will make this work regardless of which library has this code.
Problems start when you have two C++ libraries compiled with two different compilers (or different versions of the same compiler), a few things can break.
Each compiler can have its own heap, both calls to new and delete must happen in the same library so the object will be deallocated from the correct "global heap", you don't need to do this if you just use one C++ compiler, (an exception to this rule is if the library is statically linking the C standard library then it can also have its own heap). if an object got deleted from the wrong heap your app will crash with the Heap corruption error.
To guarantee both calls to new and delete happen in the same library, people define two functions.
// header
extern "C" Object* createObject();
extern "C" void deleteObject(Object*);

// .cpp
Object* createObject()
{
    return new Object();
}
void deleteObject(Object* ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
}

Those two functions will be in the same translation unit and only 1 version of them will exist, and so all calls to new and delete will happen in the same library, wrapping the deleter in a std::unique_ptr with a custom deleter just automates the deletion process.

When should you do this ?
In practice all C++ code in a project is compiled with 1 compiler, and you shouldn't care about library boundaries.
But if you are a vendor providing a closed-source C++ library, or you want people to provide plugins for your application using their own compiler, then you need to start worrying about this problem.
Note that you can make virtual function calls across different compilers, you can compile a C++ dll with MSVC and compile another dll with MinGW and use the virtual functions of the objects created in the MinGW dll inside the MSVC dll. (Because all compilers seem to have the same virtual functions ABI)

If you want to wrap the return of createObject inside a unique_ptr you need to do it in a static function in the header so any compiler that reads this header will generate its own version of unique_ptr that calls deleteObject on destruction.
// header
#include <memory>

struct Object;
extern "C" Object* createObject();
extern "C" void deleteObject(Object*);

static constexpr auto ObjectDeleter = [](Object* ptr) { deleteObject(ptr); };
using ObjectUniquePtr = typename std::unique_ptr<Object, decltype(ObjectDeleter)>;

static ObjectUniquePtr make_unique_Object()
{
    return ObjectUniquePtr{createObject()};
}


And this is also the reason why e.g. in Win32 COM all objects are internally refcounted. On Windows mixed incompatible runtimes between dlls were very common, especially in the early days.

Ok, thanks. Question regarding using the functions createObject and deleteObject. Do I need to provide them explicitely if I am creating unique_ptr of SomeClass in the describe scenario?

@PiotrG you cannot use the normal deleter of unique_ptr anymore because it just calls delete directly which we want to avoid, i added a snippet of how you could generate a unique_ptr with the correct deleter in the header.

One more thing: in your snippet, you have not explicitly provided ObjectDeleter when creating ObjectUniquePtr, only its decltype is specified in its declaration. Shouldn't be: return ObjectUniquePtr{createObject(), ObjectDeleter }; ?

@PiotrG that deleter is default constructable, and has zero size, you don't need to pass it in. another version of this pointer could be std::unique_ptr<Object*, void(*)(Object*)> which is not zero size and you need to pass the deleter explicitly, and your unique_ptr will be 2 pointers size instead of one .... this is useful if you have 2-3 different plugin libraries and you want to control which library gets to delete this object, because each one happens to be compiled with a different compiler, although at this point i might just use a shared_pointer instead for the type-erased deleter.
